# Use lodash to make function call on each item in array and merge results

Tags: lodash

I have an array like the following:

```
people = [{name: "sarah", id: 1 }, {name: "jack", id: 2 }];
```

For each item in the array, I need to make a function call passing in the id as a parameter.

This function returns:

```
{
   id: 1,
   title: "president"
}
```

I would like to take title from this result and add it to the "people" array, so the array will look like this:

```
people = [{name: "sarah", id: 1, title: "president" }, {name: "jack", id: 2, title: "cto" }];
```

Is there a way to do this using lodash? I'm trying to avoid a foreach loop.

This merges two arrays:

```
_map(people, function(obj) {
  return _.assign(obj, _.find(secondArray, {id: obj.id}));
})
```

I am trying to figure out how I can add in a my function call to this.

Comment: `assign` can take many parameters so how about adding the function call at the end? e.g. `_.assign(obj, _.find(secondArray, {id: obj.id}), getTitle(obj.id))`

Comment: that does the trick. could you answer the question, so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**assign**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) can take many parameters so you could add the call to the function as an extra parameter:

```
_.assign(obj, _.find(secondArray, {id: obj.id}), getTitle(obj.id));
```